# Moving focus from last tabbed item in modal to next parent's sibling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the following code, how can I move the focus from the last item in the subMenu modal to the next Main Nav element.

For example...

- When a user tabs off of "SubMenu 1.8", the focus needs to go to "Main Nav 2".
- When a user tabs off of "SubMenu 2.9", the focus needs to go to "Main Nav 3".
- When a user tabs off of "More info" btn, the focus can then resume down the page to the "More info" link.

Here's what I have for the HTML and jQuery. I can modify the jQuery, but can't change the structure of the HTML.

```
<nav class="main-navigation" role="none">
  <ul>
    <li role="group" class="active-main-menu"><a class="att-track active" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Main Nav 1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="group"><a role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main Nav 2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="group"><a role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main Nav 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- subMenu Modal -->
<div id="subMenu-wrapper active">
  <h4><a href="#">SubMenu Title 1.0</a></h4>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.1</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.2</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.3</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.4</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.5</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.6</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.7</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 1.8</a>
</div>
<div id="subMenu-wrapper">
  <h4><a href="#">SubMenu Title 2.0</a></h4>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.1</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.2</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.3</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.4</a>
  <h4><a href="#">SubMenu Title 2.1</a></h4>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.5</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.6</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.7</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.8</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 2.9</a>
</div>
<div id="subMenu-wrapper">
  <h4><a href="#">SubMenu Title 3.0</a></h4>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 3.1</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 3.2</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 3.3</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 3.4</a>
  <a href="#">SubMenu 3.5</a>
  <btn>Contact us</btn>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  <a href="#">More info</a>
</div>

$('.subMenu-wrapper:first-child a:last, .subMenu-container:nth-child(2) a:last, .subMenu-container:nth-child(3) a:last').one("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        $('active-main-menu').focus();
        hideModalOverlay(); // hides modal
   }
});
```

Comment: According to your requirement "When a user tabs off of "SubMenu 1.8", the focus needs to go to "Main Nav 2" . After that if user tab again what should happen ?

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML structure?

Comment: @Swati - When they're on Main Nav 2 and tab again, they should be taken to Main Nav 3. When on Main Nav 2 and they click enter, they should be taken to SubMenu Title 2.0.

Comment: @AHaworth - I can't modify the structure of the HTML.

Comment: Would be useful to know that, could you put it into your question (as otherwise the obvious way to solve this is not to use tabindex but restructure).

Comment: In your comment to @Swati what does 'click enter' mean?

Comment: @AHaworth - Updated the OP. 'Click enter' means clicking the Enter button.

Comment: I dont see an enter button.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you cannot change html, but the simplest would be here to simply add id's to the needed elements, and then refocus when it tabs off, but you mentioned that you cannot change html and that's said.

Comment: Would adding ids make a difference as any of the elements can be selected by other means if necessary.

Comment: It's just more useful, agree, so there more (ifs should be made definately)